# Qual è il significato di "rimettersi in pari con lo stomaco" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto questo passaggio che fa riferimento a un momento in cui l'autore dovette ricoverarsi in ospedale:

> Poche ore dopo ero in un letto d’ospedale. Passarono due giorni e l’amico che mi assisteva mi disse che i medici mi davano per moribondo. «Dicono che ti sei portato il male troppo tempo senza accorgertene. Che facciamo? Ti alzi e vieni via o diamo ragione a loro?» 
>          Io gli dissi: 
>         ‎«Ascolta. Li calerò nella fossa tutti quanti, loro e le loro radiografie. Qui si tratta di **rimettersi in pari con lo stomaco**».

La mia domanda è sull'espressione "rimettersi in pari con lo stomaco" che appare in questo brano. Si tratta di un modo di dire? Potreste spiegarmene il significato? Ho cercato alla voce "stomaco" in alcuni dizionari, incluso il dizionario di modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il significato di questo modo di dire in questo contesto è rifocillarsi, mangiare a sazietà.

Un esempio di uso in un contesto simile al tuo si trova in [Cari socci: anedotti e personaggi nel Novecento scarlinese](https://books.google.it/books?id=EwCmHXABMIAC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=rimettersi%20in%20pari%20con%20lo%20stomaco&source=bl&ots=afYwMnoNaZ&sig=IXtOXNGYk1BoCeGLLqX5IlBAu3s&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkjfXMgtrZAhVEtBQKHc8fAaEQ6AEINTAB#v=onepage&q=rimettersi%20in%20pari%20con%20lo%20stomaco&f=false) di Flavio Agresti

> Questo vitto forzato procurava agli Scarlinesi, tutta gente robusta e
>   d'appetito, un sacrificio mille e più volte maggiore di quello dovuto
>   al pesantissimo lavoro nei campi, più adatto alle bestie che agli
>   uomini, a cui erano addetti. Perciò, al fine di rendere più
>   sopportabile la loro situazione, decisero che, appena concluso
>   quell'impegno di lavoro, sarebbero tutti andati al ristorante a farsi
>   una bella scorpacciata di pastasciutta per ***mettersi in pari con lo
>   stomaco*** e ritemprarsi l'orgoglio, così duramente ferito da quella
>   umiliante esperienza, prima di tornare alle rispettive famiglie a
>   Scarlino.